# How do I play online with a used game?

Tags: ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one

I bought Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One, and the manual mentioned I needed to use a code on the back of the manual to activate online play.

If I bought the game used and the manual code was already used, how do I play online?

Comment: You probably cant. Yey for DRM!

Comment: For the record: I bought a new copy, I just wanted to know since my Aunt and Uncle tend to buy used games.

Answer (score 7):

You can buy a new PSN Pass on the PSN store or usually through the game.

Comment: +1 - Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One Online Pass ($9.99)
Download the Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One Online Pass to unlock the full online features of All 4 One.
File size 128 KB

Answer (score 2):

I believe they might have a DRM Pass that you may have to buy off of the PSN store ... check there I know that they did it for a few other games.